# Custom component in starting of mdx file in next js project not following indentation

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, mdxjs

I have nextjs project with below versions

```
"@mdx-js/loader": "^2.1.5",
"@mdx-js/react": "^2.1.5",
"@next/mdx": "^12.1.6",
"next": "^12.1.6",
```

I have one react component and using it in .mdx file with some text as below

`<CustomReactComponent/>, you can....`
but in output text not coming under `<p>` tag and not following proper indentation.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update next-mdx-remote package to latest version `"next-mdx-remote": "^4.2.0"`
and add this to mdx options in serialize function of remote-mdx

```
import remarkslug from 'remark-slug';
import remarkAutolinkHeadings from 'remark-autolink-headings';
import remarkCodeTitles from 'remark-code-titles';
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm';

        const mdxSource = await serialize(content, {
        mdxOptions: {
          remarkPlugins: [
            remarkGfm,
            remarkslug,
            [
              remarkAutolinkHeadings,
              {
                linkProperties: {
                  className: ['anchor']
                }
              }
            ],
            remarkCodeTitles
          ]
        }
      });
```

Now it will wrap your text beside any custom component to p tag automatically